# Why is my custom ContentControl with data triggers not showing up in the UI, though the constructor is called?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, contentcontrol

I'm using reflection and expression trees in C# to build a fairly adaptable search tool for our database. Because of this, I have a need for a custom ContentControl - termed 'MultiStyleInputBox' - which uses data triggers to adjust its ContentTemplate to the Type of input expected. The problem is, while the code builds just fine and I have confirmed that both the public and static constructors are being hit when the code executes, the ContentControl's content doesn't show up at all in my UI.

Now, I'm relatively new to writing custom XAML/C# UI control classes, but I have been able to cobble together the following:

```
<ContentControl x:Class="MyApp.MultiStyleInputBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             Name="multiStyleInputBox">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ContentControl}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding InputType, ElementName=multiStyleInputBox}" Value="{x:Type sys:DateTime}">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Value, ElementName=multiStyleInputBox}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
               <!--I have several of these triggers for different data types-->
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=multiStyleInputBox}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

And the code behind:

```
    public sealed partial class MultiStyleInputBox : ContentControl
    {
        //Dependency properties
        public Type InputType
        {
            get { return (Type)GetValue(InputTypeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(InputTypeProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty InputTypeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("InputType", typeof(Type), typeof(MultiStyleInputBox));
        public object Value
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(object), typeof(MultiStyleInputBox));

        //Constructors
        public MultiStyleInputBox() : base()
        {

        }
        static MultiStyleInputBox()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MultiStyleInputBox), 
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MultiStyleInputBox)));
        }
    }
```

I thought at one point that I might not have set the content of the ContentControl, and so I added a `<ContentPresenter/>`, but I received an error saying that the content is set more than once, so I believe that my `<Style.Setters></Style.Setters>` section is taking care of that. Otherwise, even running around using `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High"` on my bindings, I haven't so far been able to run into any useful errors.

Is there some sort of glaring issue in my code that I can immediately address (hopefully)? Do I need to reevaluate my approach to the problem?

---

Update

After suggested corrections in the answers below, here is the latest version of the code:

```
<ContentControl x:Class="MyApp.MultiStyleInputBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             Name="multiStyleInputBox">
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ContentControl}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding InputType, ElementName=multiStyleInputBox, Value="{x:Type sys:DateTime}">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Value, ElementName=multiStyleInputBox}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <!--I have several of these triggers for different data types-->
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=multiStyleInputBox}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

And the code-behind:

```
public partial class MultiStyleInputBox : ContentControl
    {
        //Dependency properties
        public Type InputType
        {
            get { return (Type)GetValue(InputTypeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(InputTypeProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty InputTypeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("InputType", typeof(Type), typeof(MultiStyleInputBox));
        public object Value
        {
            get { return GetValue(ValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(object), typeof(MultiStyleInputBox),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DateTime.Now,
                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

        //Constructors
        public MultiStyleInputBox() : base()
        {

        }
        static MultiStyleInputBox()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MultiStyleInputBox), 
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MultiStyleInputBox)));
        }
    }
```

Here is a test instantiation of the MultiStyleInputBox (I'm using Mahapps.Metro):

```
<Controls:MetroWindow
    xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
    x:Class="MyApp.TestWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
        Title="Test Window" Height="450" Width="800"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <StackPanel>
        <local:MultiStyleInputBox x:Name="TestMultiBox" Value="1" InputType="{x:Type sys:Int32}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

When I try to instantiate this class, I'm still not getting anything showing up in my UI, and the ContentControl isn't taking up any space. Even if I include `Width="50" Height="24"`, I still get nothing. I've tested setting both Value and InputType in code-behind and using a breakpoint to inspect the object, and I'm finding that, while both values get set, the Content of the ContentControl remains null.

Comment: The glaring issue is that you're creating a default style for ContentControl *children* of your content control, but it's not applied to your content control itself.

Comment: Using DataTriggers to "to adjust its ContentTemplate" and hence the whole control seems unnecessary. Instead of that, use different DataTemplates for different content types by declaring DataTemplates in a ResourceDictionary and setting their DataType property. Such a DataTemplate will automatically be chosen when you set the Content of a ContentControl.

Comment: @t-schreibs Clemens is not wrong, though I can see a point to having UI for the desired there even when `Value` is `null`. More importantly, see update to my answer. There's another issue you'll run into now that you're getting your content.

Comment: @Clemens, that's an interesting idea. To Ed Plunkett's point though, would I be able to handle null values this way?

Comment: Give it a try. I'd say that having a DataTemplate for a `null` Content is entirely pointless.

Comment: @Clemens Yeah, who needs an input for a value that hasn't been entered yet?

Comment: There should obviously be a non-null default Content value. How else would you choose the ContentTemplate by the Content type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate problem is that your style isn't applied to the ContentControl you want to apply it to. You're defining an implicit ContentControl style which will be applied to any ContentControls you create in the content of this control -- but you aren't creating any, and that's not what you want anyhow.

For a quick fix, just change `ContentControl.Resources` to `ContentControl.Style`.

```
<ContentControl x:Class="MyApp.MultiStyleInputBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             Name="multiStyleInputBox">
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ContentControl}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding InputType, ElementName=multiStyleInputBox}" Value="{x:Type sys:DateTime}">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Value, ElementName=multiStyleInputBox}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
               <!--I have several of these triggers for different data types-->
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=multiStyleInputBox}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

Your next problem will be that selecting a new DateTime in the DatePicker won't update a property bound to the `Value` property of your viewmodel. Here's the fix for that:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(object), typeof(MultiStyleInputBox),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DateTime.Now, 
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

And the last problem (or the first, perhaps) was that you weren't calling `InitializeComponent()` in the constructor, which is always required in any WPF codebehind class:

```
    public MultiStyleInputBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Comment: I'd pulled out a bunch of additional binding code when posting this, but in my MultiStyleInputBox.xaml file, I've got `SelectedDate="{Binding Value, ElementName=multiStyleInputBox, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`. The two-way binding here should take care of that issue, yes?

Comment: No, that binding will be two-way by default already, just as yours should be. With or without `Mode=TwoWay` it will update your `Value` property, which will not update whatever it's bound to in the viewmodel, because your Value property one-way by default.

Comment: Ah ok, I'm understanding what you mean now. Thanks so much for all the help so far; everything you've mentioned has obviously been a necessary fix. However, I'm still not getting my ContentControl to show up. I'm instantiating a test via `<local:MultiStyleInputBox Value="1" InputType="{x:Type sys:Int32}"/>` but it is taking up no space in my UI and has no content. Even if I set `Width="50"` and `Height="24"`, I still get nothing.

Comment: @t-schreibs Please add your current xaml and code behind to your question, including the window where it’s used. I had no trouble getting it to work, so it can’t be too difficult.

Comment: @t-schreibs You need to call `InitializeComponent();` in the constructor. I did that in my version of your code and forgot to include that in my answer. See update.

Comment: Aha! A silly oversight. Everything is working as expected now.